# How to avoid an unknown height sticky footer to overlap content with CSS only?

Tags: html, css

I want an HTML element (a footer for example) to be absolutely positioned to the bottom of a page but at the same time I don't want it to overlap the content when the viewport is small (vertically resize the browser to see the issue). I want the footer to stay after the content when the viewport is small to avoid overlapping. **Is there any CSS-only solution for that?**

Here's a fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/nunoarruda/owfz5eby/

```
<div>Content</div>
<footer>footer with absolute position</footer>

footer {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Google's homepage has this implemented but I'm unable to understand if it is a CSS-only method or it requires JavaScript. Here's a screenshot of Google's footer with `position: absolute;`
[image]

And here's a screenshot of Google's footer staying after the content and not overlapping:
[image]

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Feel free to check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30428672/483779 that I posted before, very similar situation. You can change both 60px to 200px in the fiddle, and resize the output frame and see.

Comment: @sdcr good solution but it requires a fixed height on the footer and that same amount as a margin-bottom on the body. The site I want to implement this has a responsive footer that changes height (height: auto;) according to the viewport. If I don't find a better solution I might use this technique with media queries to update the height

Comment: I'll think about it for the dynamic height, how about JS? that could make it really easy.

Comment: @sdcr I know how to do it with JS, I'm really trying to find a CSS-only solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the `flex` solution. Browser support: IE 10+

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8u368wgo/)**

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
main {
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
footer {
    background: silver;
    /* height: 200px; */
}
```

```html
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

And the CSS `table` solution. Browser support: IE 8+

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ve69qLso/)**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.main, .footer {
    display: table-row;
}
.main {
    height: 100%;
}
.footer {
    background: silver;
    /* height: 200px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">main</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: Toggle `height: 200px;` for testing the scrollbar in the jsfiddle.

Comment: The current global browser support for flexbox and viewport units might steer me away from using this but yeah it is the perfect solution :) Thanks!

Comment: @NunoArruda I've added another solution that also works on older browsers.

Comment: none of these examples work for me (FF 102.8.0esr). am I trippin

Answer (score 3):

Try this out.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>My amazing content.</p>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    /* Margin bottom by footer height */
    margin: 0 0 60px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.container {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 680px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db7f2L1w/)**

Comment: same as @sdcr solution but thanks for the effort!

Comment: @NunoArruda Not exactly, my solution doesn't require the `flex` property and having to use the `vh` unit. `flex` isn't supported for IE 9 or less so just depends on your needs.

Comment: I was referring to his first solution he put on the comments of the question :)

Comment: Just found out that Bootstrap has an example of this method :) http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: Yeah it's a common method, just search 'sticky footer' on google, there are quite a few. :)

Answer (score 2):

Building off of Pangloss' answer, you can use `margin-top: auto` on the footer; that way you don't need the `main` element CSS to push the footer down:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8u368wgo/2/)

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
footer {
  background: silver;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<main>main, or any other el here</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest way to implement the sticky footer concept. However, one thing I'd like to know. While putting a para in the footer using this concept, the para sticks vertically to the top of the footer. How do I place it in the middle? I'm trying to use "vertical-align: middle;" but it's taking no effect. Please help.

Comment: @priyamtheone add `display: flex;` `justify-content: center;` and `flex-direction: column;` to the `footer` element. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cedm8u0q/

Comment: Works great, except in Safari.

Comment: does everyone on the planet have a different idea of what a sticky footer is or there just something wrong with my machine because none of these are rendering sticky footers for me

Answer (score 0):

To give you another option, you could do it by using `calc` to give the content a height of 100% less the footer's height and then also give it a `min-height` to suit your needs - no need for any positioning.

(View the Snippet in fullscreen and resize your browser to see it in action)

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;}
html,body{height:100%;}
main{
  background:#000;
  height:calc(100% - 50px);
  min-height:300px;
}
footer{
  background:#ccc;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Give the footer a z-index.
2. Give the content position:relative, a higher z-index, and a background-color (so that when the footer travels behind it, it's no longer visible).

You can also give content a min-height or padding-bottom if you want the footer to disappear a little before it would otherwise collide with the content.

```
 .content {    
     position:relative;
     z-index:2;
     background:#FFF;
 }

 footer {
     width: 400px;
     background-color: #ccc;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     z-index:1;
 }
```

I updated your fiddle to show you what I mean. When the footer collides with the content, it will slide underneath it.
http://jsfiddle.net/owfz5eby/1/

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I want to keep the footer visible after the content and not hide it behind the content. Check the Google's homepage to see what I mean.